# How does a web API interface conceal data?

Tags: http

How does a web API interface hide data? I came across a news website where, when I click on a news article, the news is displayed one by one. However, when I inspect the API response, I couldn't find the actual content of the news. How is it possible for the news to be rendered on the webpage without being present in the API response?

Please explain the techniques or mechanisms used by developers to achieve this kind of behavior.

Thank you for your kind assistance and expertise.

Best regards

I have a suspicion that the other party might be using Unicode encoding and storing all the encodings in the client-side JavaScript. However, despite searching, I couldn't find any Unicode characters related to the news content.

Comment: It might help if you shared which website this is. There are many different ways to achieve this.

Comment: eg:https://poe.com/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are various techniques to hide data in a web API:

- One technique is to use **pagination** or **lazy loading**.
  Instead of returning the entire dataset in a single response, the server only sends a subset of the data. As the user scrolls, additional requests are made to fetch more data.
- Another technique is to use **client-side rendering**.
  The response may contain only the necessary **metadata** or **placeholders** for the content. The actual content is then fetched and rendered on the client-side using **JavaScript**. This allows for a more dynamic and better UX.

Comment: "id": "sd898s7d88f9sd78f79sd8f88s7f8sdhfsdf",
"node": {"messageId": 99335739996,"creationTime": 1705571751092368,"id": "TWVzc2FnZTo5OTMzNTczOTk5Ng==","text": "tesst","author": "human","state": "complete","contentType": "text_markdown"}

Comment: my dear friend. However, the data his provided seems to be insufficient for generating the extensive 500-word news content his mentioned. I'm unsure if the methods you previously mentioned can achieve such results, especially considering the absence of placeholders or similar symbols and the presence of only an ID-like field. Could you please provide further information regarding the implementation you're referring to?

reponse body:
"id": "sd898s7d88f9sdf","node": {"messageId": 99335739996,"creationTime": 1705571751092368,"id": WVzc2FnZTo5OTMzNTczOTk5Ng==","text": "tesst"}